# Letting Nokogiri decide whether to use #fragment or #parse

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a piece of HTML that I would like to parse with Nokogiri, but I do not know whether it is a full HTML document (with DOCTYPE,  etc) or a fragment (e.g. just a div with some elements in it).

This makes a difference for Nokogiri, because it should use #fragment for parsing fragments but #parse for parsing full documents.

Is there a way to determine whether a given piece of text is a fragment or a full HTML document?

Denis

Comment: There's good reasons to use parse in either case. It will just build a document with your html and you will be able to use xpath easier.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how trashed your page is, but

```
/^(?:\s*<!DOCTYPE)|(?:\s*<html)/
```

should work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to look for the mandatory `<html>` tag, using for instance a regular expression `/<html[\s>])/` (allowing attributes).

Is this sufficient to solve your problem?

Comment: Note that the `<html>` tag is not required in HTML5. For example, see http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/minimal-html. The `<title>` or `<body>` tags might be more appropriate.

Comment: According to the referenced article, a title tag is also not required, and neither is body.

Comment: No, but the case where a `<title>` tag is not required is exceedingly unlikely, and the `<body>` tag may only be omitted when there is no body content (another unlikely situation).